# is_unique for codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the `is_unique` rule from the Codeigniter form validation library in the following situation.

I'm trying to submit a edit user form and have the rule:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_unique[users.user_name]');
```

What if other values in the form are being changed but this value stays the same. The form is going to see that this value already exists so how would I protect it from editing if this value isn't changed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using your code as an example, the `is_unique` validation rule works by looking for a field called `user_name` in your `users` database table. If the field with the same value exists it validates as false.

To make sure it runs only when the user submits a new value, you could check the posted value  `$this->input->post('user_name')` against the value you pulled from the database to populate your form with. If they are the same, don't validate is_unique;

```
if($this->input->post('user_name') != $original_value) {
   $is_unique =  '|is_unique[users.user_name]'
} else {
   $is_unique =  ''
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Comment: What would I define original value as?

Comment: That would be the original value of the users user_name as taken from the database. The if statement compares the original user_name, with the data submitted by the user. If the user changes their username, it will check to see if that value doesn't already exist, otherwise it will just do normal validation.

Comment: So I need to set up another query to find out what the old value was then?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand completely, but if your not populating the form with data from the database, how else are you populating it?

Comment: $users = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id))->row();
$original_value = $users->user_name;

Answer (score 10):

There's a better way to go around it, I think, still using CodeIgniters' validation library...
Use edit_unique where you pass an extra parameter which is the id of the row you're editing.. See below.. I use it and works pretty fine for me.. hope it helps

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|edit_unique[users.user_name.'.$id.']');
```

Comment: The function edit_unique() available in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930074/1356425).

Answer (score 3):

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');

$this->form->validation->set_rules('something','Something','xss_clean|is_unique['tbl'.users]');

if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Way**

**Just Change isset to is_object in system/libraries/form_validation.php**

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);
    return is_object($this->CI->db) //default isset
        ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
        : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I just added that to my MY_Form_validation Controller to override that function and it works a treat. AND I can still use callbacks. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

[CodeIgniter 4](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/index.html) has already solution for that,

```php
$validation->setRules([
    'email' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email,id,{id}]',
]);

$_POST = [
    'id' => 4,
    'email' => 'foo@example.com',
];
```

then the `{id}` placeholder would be replaced with the number `4`, giving this revised rule:

```php
$validation->setRules([
    'email' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email,id,4]',
]);
```

[Official Documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#validation-placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy method that worked for me and uses well documented code (thanks to https://github.com/ivantcholakov for sharing it!). I found it referenced at https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3109#issuecomment-46346280

1. Download https://github.com/ivantcholakov/starter-public-edition-3/blob/master/platform/application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php (MIT licensed) and save it to your application at application\libraries\MY_Form_validation.php
2. Delete these two lines from __construct():

   $this->CI->load->helper('checkbox');
   $this->CI->load->helper('email');
3. Delete all the functions except __construct() and unique().
4. At the end of the __construct() method of your controller add this line:

   $this->load->library('form_validation');
5. As per the documentation of the unique() method update your validation rule to add a "unique" rule like this (e.g. if you already have required and trim rules):

   …|required|unique[tablename.fieldname,tablename.(primaryKey-used-for-updates)]|trim...

Answer (score 0):

Extend Form_validation.php library create class inside of application/libraries file name MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{
    protected $ci;
     public function __construct($config = array()){
                parent::__construct($config);
                $this->ci =& get_instance();
        }

                public function is_unique_update($str, $field){
                $explode=explode('@', $field);
                $field_name=$explode['0'];
                $field_id_key=$explode['1'];
                $field_id_value=$explode['2'];
                sscanf($field_name, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field_name);

                 if(isset($this->ci->db)){
                        if($this->ci->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field_name => $str,$field_id_key=>$field_id_value))->num_rows() === 0){
                             $this->ci->form_validation->set_message('is_unique_update', 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.');
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }


            }
}
```

Now in your controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_unique_update[users.user_name@id@'.$id.']');
```

"@" I used for explode the string
where id is primary key of users table
and $id is the value of id.
Now you can use this is_unique_update validation in any controller.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but maybe some new people experience this problem and this is the solution for it. 
I bet your are using Modular Extensions (HMVC) and you have created a new library, MY_Form_validation. You did id for callbacks, so you have this line of code on your class in order to use callbacks:

```
$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;
```

Well, the solution to this is whenever you want to use "is_unique" you must delete this line of code "$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;" from the class. I have experienced this problem and i fix it this way, it works fine now.

If you realy want to use callbacks "$this->form_validation->CI =& $this;", then do it only on required "methods" / "functions" where you don't want to use is_unique.

Answer (score 0):

### This code helpful for unique validation to create and update function...

In controller

Add this form validation code in both create and update function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('order_no', 'Order no', 'required|callback_check_order_no');
```

Add this call back function in controller

```
function check_order_no($order_no) {        
        if($this->input->post('id'))
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
        else
            $id = '';
        $result = $this->Data_model->check_unique_order_no($id, $order_no);
        if($result == 0)
            $response = true;
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_order_no', 'Order no already exist');
            $response = false;
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

In model

```
function check_unique_order_no($id = '', $order_no) {
        $this->db->where('order_no', $order_no);
        $this->db->where('status', "A");

        if($id) {
            $this->db->where_not_in('id', $id);
        }
        return $this->db->get('delivery_order')->num_rows();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using codeigniter3 and it shows me error when I check username on updating the value, is_unique is not designed to work with update scenario
so using @Anthony Mutisya's answer, here is the complete solution

in your controller, add this line while validation username of the current user with the database

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|edit_unique[users.user_name.'.$id.']');
```

You can get that `$id` from your submited form.

Now, add the following function to `/system/libraries/Form_Validation.php` this file. `System` folder is present in your root of CodeIgniter3 folder.

```php
/**
* edit_unique // for check on update value
*
* Check if the input value doesn't already exist
* in the specified database field.
*
* @param    string  $str
* @param    string  $field
* @return   bool
*/
function edit_unique($value, $params)  {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    $CI->form_validation->set_message('edit_unique', "Sorry, that %s is already being used.");
    
    list($table, $field, $current_id) = explode(".", $params);
    
    $query = $CI->db->select()->from($table)->where($field, $value)->limit(1)->get();
    
    if ($query->row() && $query->row()->id != $current_id)
    {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine in my case