# Codeigniter - edit form (repopulating) with edit_unique

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-form-helper

It seems that the `edit_unique` function, which is desribed [here - *Validating Uniqueness In CodeIgniter When Updating A Record*](https://forrst.com/posts/Validating_Uniqueness_In_CodeIgniter_When_Updati-DDA), kills the `set_value` function.

All works fine, which something like this...

```
echo form_input('username', set_value('username',$user->username));
```

But when using the `edit_unique` validation, the value is empty after submitting the form. Post-Variables are ok  and also the validation has no errors - but the value is not set.

Any idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 8):

Ok - found it myself. There was no return value in case of beeing true. Perhaps anyone faces the same problem... with this function, it works:

```
function edit_unique($value, $params)  {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();

    $CI->form_validation->set_message('edit_unique', "Sorry, that %s is already being used.");

    list($table, $field, $current_id) = explode(".", $params);

    $query = $CI->db->select()->from($table)->where($field, $value)->limit(1)->get();

    if ($query->row() && $query->row()->id != $current_id)
    {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `edit_unique` usage can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779434/1179841)

Answer (score 0):

Petra's answer works well, if for some reason it doesn't work for you, check if your primary key is 'id',  if not you'll need to make some changes.

Change

```php
list($table, $field, $current_id) = explode(".", $params);

if ($query->row() && $query->row()->id != $current_id)
```

to

```php
list($table, $field, $current_id, $key) = explode(".", $params);

if ($query->row() && $query->row()->$key != $current_id)
```

Then add the rule like:

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'form_field', 
    'Form Label', 
    'required|trim|edit_unique[table.column.' . $edit . '.unique]'
);
```

Where  `unique` is your unique/primary key and `$edit` is it's value.