# Codeigniter: Update unable to update with same username

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have this set of code which is working controller:

```
public function edit_book(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('bName', 'Book Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[255]|is_unique[books.book_name]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Description', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|callback__alpha_dash_space|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('publisher', 'Publisher', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pages', 'Pages', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|numeric|max_length[5]|is_natural');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $month = $this->input->post('months');
            $day = $this->input->post('days');
            $year = $this->input->post('years');
            $pDate = date("d-m-Y",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[9]|decimal');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'Quantity', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[3]|numeric|is_natural');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('genres', 'Genres', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[255]|alpha_dash_space');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reviews', 'Reviews', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags|max_length[255]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            $this->load->model('model_books');
            if ($this->model_books->edit_book($pDate)){
                $data = array(
                    'title' => 'Edited Page'
                );
                $data2 = array(
                    'operation' => 'edited',
                    'repeat' => '',
                    'page' => 'edit'
                );
                $this->load->view("header", $data);
                $this->load->view("operation_done", $data2);
                $this->load->view("footer");
            } else {
                echo "Error editing books";
            }
        } else {
            $this->edit_error();
        }
    }
```

The view:

```
<?php

    echo form_open('admin/edit_book');

    echo validation_errors();

    foreach($books as $book) {
        $bID = $book->book_id;
        $bName = $book->book_name ;
        $desc = $book->description;
        $author = $book->author;
        $publisher = $book->publisher;
        $pages = $book->pages;
        $pDate = $book->publication_date;
        $price = $book->price;
        $status = $book->status;
        $quantity = $book->quantity;
        $genres = $book->genres;
        $reviews = $book->reviews;
    };

    echo "<p style= font-size:20px;color:#00FF33;>Book ID:". $bID . "</p>";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'bID',
              'id'          => 'bID',
              'value'       => $bID,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'type'        => 'hidden'
            );
    echo form_input($data);

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'bName',
              'id'          => 'bName',
              'value'       => $bName,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Book Name',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'desc',
              'id'          => 'desc',
              'value'       => $desc,
              'rows'        => '4',
              'cols'        => '34',
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'placeholder' => 'Description',
            );
    echo form_textarea($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'author',
              'id'          => 'author',
              'value'       => $author,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Author',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'publisher',
              'id'          => 'publisher',
              'value'       => $publisher,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Publisher',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'pages',
              'id'          => 'pages',
              'value'       => $pages,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Pages',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $months = array('' => 'Month',
                 '1'  => 'Jan',
                 '2'  => 'Feb',
                 '3'  => 'Mar',
                 '4'  => 'Apr',
                 '5'  => 'May',
                 '6'  => 'Jun',
                 '7'  => 'Jul',
                 '8'  => 'Aug',
                 '9'  => 'Sep',
                 '10' => 'Oct',
                 '11' => 'Nov',
                 '12' => 'Dec'
                );
         $days[''] = 'Day';         
         for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
            $days[$i] = $i;
         }

         $start_year = date("Y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")-80));
         $years[''] = 'Year';

         for ($i=$start_year;$i<=date("Y");++$i) {
            $years[$i] = $i;
         }
         $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $pDate);
    echo form_label('Publication Date','pDate')."<br/>".
        form_dropdown('days',$days, $date->format("d"), 'required="required"'). " " . form_dropdown('months',$months, $date->format("m"), 'required="required"'). " " . form_dropdown('years',$years, $date->format("Y"), 'required="required"');
    echo "<br /><br />";


    echo form_label('$:');
    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'price',
              'id'          => 'price',
              'value'       => $price,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '34',
              'placeholder' => 'Price',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    echo "<p>Status: ";
    $statusOptions = array(
                  ''    => '',
                  'Available'   => 'Available',
                  'Out-Of-Stock'  => 'Out-Of-Stock',
                  'Requires Ordering'  => 'Requires Ordering',
                  'Archived' => 'Archived'
                );
    echo form_dropdown('status', $statusOptions, $status, 'required="required"');
    echo "</p>";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'quantity',
              'id'          => 'quantity',
              'value'       => $quantity,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Quantity',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'genres',
              'id'          => 'genres',
              'value'       => $genres,
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'size'        => '35',
              'placeholder' => 'Genres',
            );
    echo form_input($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $data = array(
              'name'        => 'reviews',
              'id'          => 'reviews',
              'value'       => $reviews,
              'rows'        => '4',
              'cols'        => '34',
              'style'       => 'font-size:18px',
              'placeholder' => 'Reviews',
            );
    echo form_textarea($data);
    echo "<br /><br />";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('edit_book', 'Edit');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

Everything works fine, however whenever i want to edit the book and not change the book name, the validation check will say that the book already existed in the database and doesn't allow me to update the record that i have changed, unless i change the book name too, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are editing you can use this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|edit_unique[users.user_name.'.$id.']');
```

and the function edit_unique() is available  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928650/codeigniter-edit-form-repopulating-with-edit-unique/15930074#15930074).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `tablename.fieldname` is correct  Or

Try to change `is_unique[books.book_name]` to `is_unique[books.bName]`

Comment: Yup in the database it is book_name, tried to change to bName but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do not remove your validation.

Only include the validation when the name is different to the existing one. Otherwise Coideigniter wont allow you to create a duplicated field. Youll need to manually check if the name was changed or not.

Comment: Hmm do you have an example how i could go about doing this?