# How to check column record present or not if not display error message else insert into database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to check if record is exist then fire error message else insert into database using codeigniter

**model.php**

```
public function insert_profile($data){
     $this->db->insert('profile', $data);      
}
```

**controller.php**

```
public function empprofile(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[6]',
            array(
                'required' => 'enter your name'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtemail', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email',
            array(
                'required' => 'enter email'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtvpno', 'Vastipatrak No', 'trim|required|min_length[11]',
            array(
                'required' => 'select Vastipatrak No'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtfield', 'Field', 'trim|required',
            array(
                'required' => 'enter Field'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtcontact', 'Phone No', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]',
            array(
                'required' => 'select Phone No'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtexp', 'Experience', 'trim|required',
            array(
                'required' => 'enter Experience'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtage', 'Age', 'trim|required',
            array(
                'required' => 'enter age'));        

        if($this->form_validation->run() ==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('submitprofile');         
        }
        else{           
            $data = array(
                'Name' => $this->input->post('txtname'),
                'Email' => $this->input->post('txtemail'),
                'VPNo' => $this->input->post('txtvpno'),
                'Field' => $this->input->post('txtfield'),
                'Phone' => $this->input->post('txtcontact'),
                'Exp' => $this->input->post('txtexp'),
                'Age' => $this->input->post('txtage')
            );
            $result= $this->mymodel->insert_profile($data);
            if ($result == FALSE) {
                echo "Vastipatrak No already exist";                    
            } 
            elseif ($result == 0) {
                echo "Something Went Wrong";
             } 
            else{
                echo "You have successfully registred with KDOJobs";
            }
            redirect(site_url('talents'));
        }
    }
```

What i can do to check if record is exists or not if yes then display error

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692473/is-unique-for-codeigniter-form-validation

Comment: Any unique field ??

Comment: 'VPNo' is unique field @Abdulla

Comment: @RomilLodaya so you need before insert to DB check is there anything exist and if exist retun error and if not isnert it ? is it ??

Comment: Yes you correct @Abdulla

Comment: @RomilLodaya check my asnwer below

Answer (score 0):

**In Model**

```
public function insert_profile($data)
{
    $VPNo = $data['VPNo'];
    $query = $this-db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE vpno = '$VPNo' ");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if (count($result) > 0) 
    {
        # data exist
        return FALSE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->db->insert('profile', $data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) 
        {
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }       
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$result = $this->mymodel->insert_profile($data);

if ($result == FALSE) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Data exist');
} 
elseif ($result == 0) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something Went Wrong');
 } 
else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfullly Inserted');
}

/*
    In your code you using redirect(). So its better to add session like Flash Data. 
    So once you redirect as soon as function success you can access it in redirected page.

    Setting Flash Data
        If error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Data exist');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Something Went Wrong');

        If Success
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfullly Inserted');

    Accessing Flash data

        if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))
        {
            echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
        }


*/

redirect(site_url('talents'));
```

---

**Links**

1. [Flashdata in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata)

Comment: what should be in where clause?

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE VPNo=".'$data');

Comment: @RomilLodaya no  echo this and post  he value `$data['VPNo']`

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE VPNo=".$data['VPNo']);

Comment: @RomilLodaya no Comment the query code and just add this and post data. `echo $data['VPNo']`

Comment: can you write down whole query?

Comment: in model comment all code starting from here `$query = $this-db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE ")` .. to end and top of the commented code. add `print_r($data);die;`

Comment: OK i commented then?

Comment: add this `print_r($data);die;`

Comment: Array ( [Name] => ABC [Email] => abc@gmail.com [VPNo] => BDLO0400604 [Field] => Computer [Phone] => 9876543210 [Exp] => 0 [Age] => 24 )

Comment: @RomilLodaya check now this 2 Chnaged.   `$VPNo = $data['VPNo'];
  $query = $this-db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE vpno = '$VPNo' ");`

Comment: I have edited echo if already exist-
`if ($result == FALSE) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>
        Vastipatrak No already exist</strong></div>";        
    }`

Comment: it means ID is exist

Comment: but no display on talent page

Comment: you using redirect at the end ??

Comment: Yes redirect at the end

Comment: so i have to use flash data  by replacing `echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><strong>
        Vastipatrak No already exist</strong></div>";`

Comment: In View `if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))
{
 ?>
 <div class='alert alert-success'>
  <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
  <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></strong>
 </div>";
 <?php
 
}`

Comment: same change this `$this->session->flashdata('error')` to this `$this->session->flashdata('success')`. thereis 2 place to chnage

Comment: in elseif part `elseif(!empty($this->session->flashdata('success'))) {?>
            <div class="alert alert-success"> 
               <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label='close'>&times;</a> 
               <strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?></strong> 
            </div> 
         <?php }`

Comment: chnage here `elseif(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error'))` and here `$this->session->flashdata('error');` with `error` to `success`

Comment: i did but from controller message will display?? like data is exist

Comment: Hey man !! remove this `echo "Vastipatrak No already exist";` and add like this `$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Data exist');`

Comment: can you salve this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398928/how-can-i-get-individual-record-by-id-using-codeigniter)

Comment: @RomilLodaya likevise add others too if success add `$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfullly Inserted');`

Comment: @RomilLodaya check my answer. in if  part

Comment: can you resolve this error [Record by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398928/how-can-i-get-individual-record-by-id-using-codeigniter)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: [display record by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398928/how-can-i-get-individual-record-by-id-using-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to use **is_unique[table.coloum_name]** , I think, still using CodeIgniters' validation library... Use is_unique where you pass an extra parameter which is the id of the row you're editing.. See below.. I use it and works pretty fine for me.. **is_unique[table.coloum_name]** hope it helps

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|is_unique[table.coloum_name]', array( 'required' => 'enter your name'));
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html