# form_validation : error message array shows the default

Tags: codeigniter

I'm working on a `form_validation`. I have set the error messages, but it only shows the first error I've set. Other than that, it shows the default message.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]',
    array(
      'required'=>'Empty email',
      'is_unique[user.email]'=>'Email has been registered')
);
```

If I don't fill the email form, it shows 'Empty email'. If I write the email the same as in database, it shows the default error of CI : 'The Email field must contain a unique value.'

How I can show 'Email has been registered'?

Comment: @Vickel those answers have nothing to do with OPs question

Comment: actually the problem is not only in `is_unique`. I only show the one. Another problems also appear, where the first error_message is showed, but the next error_message shows the default string

Comment: @Vickel well it all got sorted, and I'm not sure where you read any of that although the information you posted would be helpful as a side note. OPs question was rather clear to me: How I can show 'Email has been registered'? as it is showing the *default* message.

Comment: @Alex I've retracted my CV as duplicate

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694798/2275490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is\_unique for codeigniter form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692473/is-unique-for-codeigniter-form-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]',
    array(
      'required'=>'Empty email',
      'is_unique'=>'Email has been registered')
);
```

DOCS: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#cascading-rules

I suspect you aren't getting the right error message because you shouldn't repeat `user.email` for the errors array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) for another error_message, i repeat the `[something]` . When I removed it, it shows the error_message I've declared.